# How to know the time period server response in the Dio library?

Tags: flutter, dio

How to know the time period server response in the [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) library?

I use [postman](https://www.postman.com/), it returns `status`, `time period`, `size` of the response, ...

[image]

How to get values in [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) lib? (I need it to write log)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [stop watch](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html) to measure how much the request took

```
var stopWatch = Stopwatch();
    
stopWatch.start();
performReques();
stopWatch.stop();

// convert the duration to string
var elapsedString = stopWatch.elapsed.toString();

// or just get duration in seconds
var elapsedSeconds = stopWatch.elapsed.inSeconds;
```

Comment: How to get size of response?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library but if the response if a string, you just need to count how many bytes represent the string you got.

Comment: @HuuBaoNguyen can you please share the code sample in which you use the above answer. I'm not able to understand how i can get that time?